# unable to send a base 64 image to server with angular js

Tags: angularjs, image, base64

i would like to send a base 64 image to the server side using the $http.get

```
$http.get(myurl+'?image='+image)
```

the image variable looks like:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABOYAAAJYCAYAAADG7OkVAAAgAElEQVR4Xuy9CXhV1bn//w0Jmc/JAA51......
```

but i have a http error when executing the url: **400 (Bad request)**

i think that the problem is due to the image variable length = 114498

how can i send a base 64 image using angular ?

Comment: Don't use GET. Use POST or PUT. GET is for... getting things from the server. POST and PUT are for... posting or putting things on the server.

Comment: the image will be used for a server side processing , after a list of Results will be sent from the server to the client side, that's why i used get

Comment: You can send a response body to a POST or PUT request.

Comment: if I decrease the length of the variable image I can access to the server without problem. so the problem is due to the image lenght, and i don't know how to call the server side using the image variable with its real length

Comment: The length of a GET URL is limited. There's no way around it. Use POST or PUT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use http post and suppose if you are using multi form data then you have to use

```
        var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(url, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){
        //success
    })
    .error(function(){
        //failed
    });
```

where file is the actual file you are sending to server